# Hide File Name in source link

Tags: php, javascript

I need to secure my video files from website. So, I need to decode my files name. I used the following code. But the video not playing.

```
    <?php
    $str1 = 'movie.mp4';
    $enc1 = base64_encode($str1);
    $str2 = 'movie.swf';
    $enc2 = base64_encode($str2);
    $str3 = 'movie.ogg';
    $enc3 = base64_encode($str3);
    $str4 = 'movie.webm';
    $enc4 = base64_encode($str4);
    echo "<video width='320' height='240' controls>
         <source src='".$enc1."' type='video/mp4'>
         <source src='".$enc3."' type='video/ogg'>
         <source src='".$enc4."' type='video/webm'>
         <object data='".$enc1."' width='320' height='240'>
         <embed src='".$enc2."' width='320' height='240'>
         </object></video> ";
?>
```

Comment: you need to handle the base64_encoded file name through a redirection script and convert it back to original name or rename your files to the base64 encoded name

Answer (score 1):

The reason the video is not playing is because the file you specify in src does not exist, since it is the encoded string and not the actual filename.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to "hide" a filename is pointless. If you want the videos to be watchable by users, the user needs some URL where he can access the file. The URL will always by definition be public and visible to the user, otherwise it could not be used to access anything. What that URL is exactly is totally up to you. It can be the real name of the file or some random id which you somehow associate with the file on the server. It doesn't matter to the user. All that matters is that the requested data is served when the URL is accessed.

If you want to show the file only to specific users, you're looking for an authorization system, not for obfuscating the URL.

Answer (score 0):

By this way file not found error will occur try to do something given below.

You can do one thing make a function which reads video file in bytes n return to player just pass  the video name n path to function n play video without any url like a streaming

Comment: i dont know how to make function. Please help me. If you have any sample code, please give to me.